# Mod rewrite apache - rewriting only base url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite 
`www.site.com/a/b/?param1=one&param2=two`
in
`www.site.com/c/d/e/?param1=one&param2=two`.

Where www.site.com/a/b does not exists. I tried with

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteRule ^a/b/(.*)$ www.site.com/c/d/e/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/a/b/(.*)$ /c/d/e/$1 [QSA,L]
```

There is no need for adding the incompleate domain. If you want that the users visit a second domain you have to add the `R` option and the protocol. For a redirect to a second domain try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/a/b/(.*)$ http://www.site.com/c/d/e/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not work! Sure it's correct? the (.*) should be mapped into $1 right? Should I investigate the fact www.site.com/a/b actually does not exist on server and using something like RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d or some other condition?

Comment: The `(.*)` will be matched to `$1` see also the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). You may also need to add a [rewrite base](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). Other conditions seems not to be nessesary in this case.